# Print accumulated sums in C++ in a recursive function

Tags: c++, string, c++11, printing

So I have this function and these global variables.

```
int recurs=0;
std::string sign="";
void count2(int k, std::vector<int> d, int total, int temp, bool flag, unsigned short int pos){
    std::string mas="+";
    std::string menos="-";
    if(pos==(d.size())){
        total+=temp;
        if(total==k){
            result++;
            std::cout << sign << "=" << k<<std::endl;
            str="";
        }
        recurs++;
        return;
    }    
    //Sum sign.
    sign=sign.substr(0,sign.size()-recurs*2);
    sign.append(mas+=std::to_string(d[pos]));
    count2(k,d,total+temp,+d[pos],true,pos+1);  
    //Rest sign
    sign=sign.substr(0,sign.size()-recurs*2);
    sign.append(menos+=std::to_string(d[pos]));
    count2(k,d,total+temp,-d[pos],false,pos+1);  
    //Append digit
    if(flag==true)
        count2(k,d,total,10*temp-d[pos],true,pos+1);
    else
        count2(k,d,total,+10*temp+d[pos],false,pos+1);
}
```

The function is called like this:
`count2(6,{1,2,3,3,3},0,0,true,0);`

**What it does:** Given a vector v, it makes combinations of sums and substractions and numbers and everytime that this combination equals the first parameter, a global variable `result` is increased. For example, `count2(6,{1,2,3,3,3},0,0,true,0);` would make `result` be 5. Since there is 5 ways to sum/sub 6 with those numbers, e.g.: `1+2+3+3-3` `1+2-3+3+3` and some others. It works perfectly. Also, the variable string `str` is not used.

**What is wrong?** Nothing, but I'd like to see which these combinations are. I'd like the function to print thinks like:

```
1+2+3+3-3
1+2-3+3+3
-1-2+3+3+3
1+2+3-3+3
```

**What is the question?** I'd like to know how to correctly print the operatins that make total be equal to k. 
If you were to [run this code in ideone](http://ideone.com/aOR2TM), it would print: YES, This is my actual outcome. But is not correct since there's no sum such as +3 or +3+3+3+3+3+3+....

```
+1+2+3+3-3=6
+3=6
+3-3+3-3-3+3+3=6
+3-3+3-3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-2+3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-1+2+3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-2+3+3+3=6
+3-3+3-3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-2+3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-1+2+3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-2+3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+2+3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3+3+3-3-3+3-3+3-3-2+3+3+3=6
```

**The correct outcome** *could* look like:

```
1+2+3+3-3
1+2+3-3+3
1+2-3+3+3
```

-1-2+3+3+3

**Question answered!**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @NeilKirk How do I print the correct operations? Like `1+2+3+3-3
1+2-3+3+3
-1-2+3+3+3
1+2+3-3+3` and such.

Comment: By passing the vector d by value, you are copying it several times. This is inefficient. Pass by const reference. You should return the result instead of modifying a global variable. Why are mas and menos not local variables?

Comment: @NeilKirk It is supposed to be inefficient. We're going on backtracking after this. Do not worry about memory consumption. :) mas and menos are not local variables because no particual reason, I could change it right away, that wouldn't affect my result nor answer the question. :/

Comment: It is basically an algorithm/design problem.

Your count2 is doing too much at the same time: 1) recursion to exhaust the combination, 2)check the result and 3) print the result
If I were you I will use some simple scripting language to prototype first

Comment: @AnthonyKong I'm afraid I'd copy-paste the comment I just made to Neil Kirk, bro.

Comment: @DavidMerinos: the code doesn't seem to compile and doesn't include a complete example.  Creating a compileable example would help others to help you.  It's not clear what you want the code to print.

Comment: @Edward I put I link in the post, here's the link again: http://ideone.com/aOR2TM

Comment: @DavidMerinos: not helpful.  That shows the same thing I get when I run the code under Linux using `g++ --std=c++11` and running the resulting executable.  I still don't know what your **desired** outcome might be.

Comment: @Edward it seems to be working ok here. http://es.tinypic.com/r/fky6v4/8. Everythin is on the post, I'd like my program to print the correct sums: `1+2+3+3-3
1+2-3+3+3
-1-2+3+3+3
1+2+3-3+3 ` Instead of the output of ideone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally count2 looks like this:

```
void count2(int k, std::vector<int> d, int total, int temp, bool flag, unsigned short int pos, std::vector<std::string> s){
    //std::cout << temp << " ";
    if(pos==(d.size())){
        total+=temp;
        if(total==k){
            result++;
            for(unsigned short int i=0;i<d.size();i++){
                std::cout << s[i] << d[i];
            }
            std::cout << "=" << k <<"\n";
        }
        return;
    }
    s[pos]="+";
    count2(k,d,total+temp,+d[pos],true,pos+1,s);
    //put a - sign in pos
    s[pos]="-";
    count2(k,d,total+temp,-d[pos],false,pos+1,s);
    if(pos==0) return;
    //Append digit
    if(flag==true){
        s[pos]="";
        //std::cout << "<0 " << 10*temp-d[pos] << " ";
        count2(k,d,total,(10*temp-d[pos]),true,pos+1,s);
    }
    else{
        s[pos]="";
        //std::cout << ">0" << 10*temp+d[pos] << " ";
        count2(k,d,total,10*temp+d[pos],false,pos+1,s);
    }

}
```

You can see instead of using a string variable, I'm using a string vector, which makes it suitable for the recursion call.

[Give it a try on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/p2tp5t)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind me changing the function signature a little bit, may I suggest the following?

```
int recurs = 0;
void count2(int k, std::vector<int> d, int total = 0, std::string temp = "", unsigned short pos = 0)
{
    if(pos == d.size())
    {
        //test total number
        if(total == k)
        {
            std::cout << temp <<"=" << k << std::endl;
            recurs++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //test each operator on next number in sequence
        count2(k, d, total + d[pos], temp + ((pos) ? "+":"") + std::to_string(d[pos]), pos + 1);
        count2(k, d, total - d[pos], temp + "-" + std::to_string(d[pos]), pos + 1);
    }
}
```

The conditional operator will remove the '+' sign from the beginning. Default values make the function easier to call from main or wherever. By sending temp as a `string`, it is easier to keep track of the final equation, as well as removing it as a global variable. It also removes the need for your `bool flag` variable. Last, `total` is updated in the function call to remove clutter from the function body.

Comment: This works but I still need combinations like 123+45. A solution has been already found.